# What causes ODBC connection error 08001 ssl security error

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I can access SSIS server and DB from SSMS on local desktop, getting results from `select * from sysjobs`. In trying to access the SSIS server and DB from python 3.7 64-bit, using connection string 
`Driver={SQL Server}; Server=BSWHPACTIANDBD1; Database=msdb; Trusted_Connection=True`,   I cannot connect to the database using pypyodbc or pyodbc;

failure is here: 
`connection = X.connect(connect_string), where X = pyodbc|pypyodbc`

pyodbc error is

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error (18) (SQLDriverConnect);
>   [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen
>   (SECDoClientHandshake()). (772)')

pypyodbc error is

> pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error')

Windows 10, 64-bit

Any suggestions or ideas, please?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on my windows PC and solved it as below:

Downloaded & installed a new SQL Server driver (for me it was below page, maybe changes with time)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Then on your PC go to **Administrative tools -> ODBC Data Source (64 or 32 bit) -> drivers**

Then take the name of the driver you just installed and use it in your python connection

```
import pyodbc
try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', # this is the name
        server='hostname.com',
        database='DB_NAME',
        uid='user_id',
        pwd='password')
    print(conn)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: I just had to choose an already installed more up-to-date driver and it was solved.